# Checking if the author of a message is an Administrator

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.io

I'm writing a Discord bot that uses the following code to detect and process user messages:

```
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
  //Message handling and response code goes here
});
```

I want to add a command that only works if the user who sent it has the Administrator permission. Is there a way I could do this?

Comment: Are you sure this is a `Discord.JS` question? DiscordJS events don't really look like that, and that tag should only be used for questions for DiscordJS

Comment: @André OP appears to be using `discord.io` (this is why my discord bots event handlers look like)

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example how you could do this:

```
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return console.log('THIS USER HAS ADMINISTRATOR PERMISSIONS!')
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

More up to date answer:

```js
function isAdmin(msg) {
  return msg.member.permissionsIn(msg.channel).has("ADMINISTRATOR")
}
```